# Retrieve minsdk of another installed application

Tags: android

Given packageinfo and applicationinfo objects, is there any way to directly pull the minsdk value of another installed app? Or failing that to directly pull out the manifest and parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. You have to create the package context and then use that to pull out the manifest and parse it manually. Here is the code snippet I used to accomplish what I needed.

```
Context otherAppContext = context.createPackageContext(packageName, CONTEXT_RESTRICTED);
XmlResourceParser xmlResourceParser = otherAppContext.getAssets().openXmlResourceParser("AndroidManifest.xml");
int eventType = xmlResourceParser.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
             Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Start document");
    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        String startTag = xmlResourceParser.getName();
             Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Start tag " + startTag);
        if (startTag.equals("uses-sdk")) {
            int count = xmlResourceParser.getAttributeCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String text = xmlResourceParser.getAttributeName(i);
                if (text.equals("minSdkVersion")) {
                    minSdkVersion = xmlResourceParser.getAttributeIntValue(i, -1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "End tag " + xmlResourceParser.getName());
    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Text " + xmlResourceParser.getText());
    }
    eventType = xmlResourceParser.next();
}
```

works like a charm. don't forget to close the resource parser somewhere.